# Как правильно сформировать SQL запрос в моем случае?

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте. Сейчас распишу всё по полочкам.

У нас имеется реферальная система, пользователь регистрируется под реферальной ссылкой, ему назначается ref_id (то есть id пользователя чьим рефералом он является) как можно увидеть на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше. Предо мной стоит задача сделать такую штуковину, выбрать имя и фамилию пользователя чьим рефералом является человек и вывести это в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, до чего удалось допетрить это сформировать вот такой запрос:

```
<div class="name">
  <?
                        $takereferal = mysql_query("SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM `users` WHERE `ref_id` = `ref_id`");
                        $givereferal = mysql_fetch_array($takereferal);//Извлекаем все данные пользователя с данным id
                        ?>
    <span>Реферер</span>
    <span><? echo $givereferal['first_name'] ?><br><? echo $givereferal['last_name'] ?></span>
</div>
```

Который возвращает такой массив:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что в принципе недалеко от истины, а теперь мне нужно сделать чтобы он выводил это дело индивидуально под каждого пользователя, смена ref_id в БД не приносит результата и на первом месте в любом случае остается "Мария Лоскутова".

Подскажите пожалуйста, как доработать эту штуку? :)

Comment: Вот если вы в php сделаете `if($a==$a) ...` вы думаю понимаете,  что такое условие выполнится в любом случае, потому что переменная равна самой себе. Вот в SQL точно так же, когда вы пишите `ref_id=ref_id` вы поле таблицы сравниваете с ним самим и как это ни странно, условие всегда истинно (кроме случая если ref_id is null) и запрос разумеется возвращает все записи из таблицы. А так как order by не задан то он возвращает их в том виде как они лежат на диске

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В SQL-запросе находится ошибка из-за которой вывод неверен:

```
SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM `users` WHERE `ref_id` = `ref_id`
```

Запрос должен быть в таком виде:

```
SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM `users` WHERE `ref_id` = REFERER_ID
```

То есть код:

```
$takereferal = mysql_query("SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM `users` WHERE `ref_id` = " . $user['id']); // $user это переменная пользователя, который просматривается
```

Comment: Синтаксическая ошибка: https://imgur.com/a/IpFnF

Comment: @user234223 простите, но по вашему скриншоту я ничего не могу сказать.

Comment: Ныне код выглядит так: https://imgur.com/a/c9y9z

Comment: Туда же прикрепил скриншот того, что возвращает SQL запрос

Comment: Моя ошибка, забыл убрать обратные кавычки из запроса. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Если мы выполняем в таком виде: https://imgur.com/a/iutQ6

Получаем пустую строку: https://imgur.com/a/krcvO

Comment: Если же в таком: https://imgur.com/a/L9aAm

Получаем ошибку: https://imgur.com/a/PAIC2

Comment: Покажите вывод переменной `$user_full_info`.

Comment: Она однако выводит id пользователя, судя по всему. Как быть :)?

https://imgur.com/a/3b312

Comment: Что выводит ID? Пожалуйста, пишите как можно больше информации.

Comment: Давайте ещё раз объясню, есть пользователь, допустим под 229 id, мы другому пользователю назначаем ref_id 229 (https://imgur.com/a/9G6vf), то есть у него в профиле должно вывестись что его реферал не "Мария Лоскутова", а пользователь под 229 id. На данный момент мы имеем такой скрипт: https://imgur.com/a/jVHpM

Comment: Ошибся на первом скриншоте, не реферала а реферера.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66489/discussion-between-egor-smolyakov-and-user234223).

Comment: Странно, не позволяет писать в чате...

Comment: Напишите свою почту, там поговорим. Здесь нет смысла.